# snowflake_table to add column-level comments using Terraform

Tags: terraform, multiple-columns, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl

As a data modeler, I have fully annotated my data model and would like to create my snowflake table(s) with column-level comments.

I would like to use the snowflake_table resource to create a table with column level comments.

From pure-DDL perspective, I would like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTBL 
    (COL1 STRING comment 'hello'
   , COL2 INT comment 'goodbye' ) 
COMMENT = 'test table'
```

To be supported while preparing Terraform DDLs in the nested schema for column (as such):

```
resource "snowflake_table" "my_tbl" {
  name     = "MYTBL"
  database = "MYDB"
  schema   = "MYSCHEMA"
  column   {
            name = "COL1"
            type = "STRING"
            comment = "hello"
  }
  column   {
            name = "COL2"
            type = "INT"
            comment = "goodbye"
  } 
  comment  = "test table"

  depends_on = [snowflake_schema.schema]
}
```

It generate error while executing through Terraform however it works perfect without Terraform. Anyone has used Terraform to push DDLs into Snowflake or any DB/Schema with addition to column level comments?

Comment: What is the error it is generating?

Comment: Hi @Ahsan - can you copy paste here the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked with `terraform-provider-snowflake 0.25.15`

```
resource snowflake_table table2 {
  database            = snowflake_database.database.name
  schema              = snowflake_schema.schema.name
  name                = var.table2_name

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
    nullable = true
    comment = "id column comment"
  }

  column {
    name     = "data"
    type     = "VARCHAR(16777216)"
    nullable = false
    comment = "data column comment"
  }
  comment = "table comment"
}
```